# How to define relationships mapping between entities that are not in the same JSON document in RestKit?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Using RestKit 0.20.2

Example:
I set up 2 core data entities 'Album' and 'Song' and relationships to define that an album has several songs and a song belong to one album.

I made the entities mapping and I can successfully display a list of albums.

I call :

`/albums` to get the albums

`/albums/:albumId/songs` to get the songs of the album specified by `albumId`

I never have a single JSON document holding an album and its songs at the same time. (all RestKit examples available on github assume that you work on a single JSON document holding all the entities together)

How do I set the relationships between both entities in order to make RestKit write that correctly in my Core Data object store ?

Comment: The request that you make to the server to get the songs for an album should have the album identity in the URL path - yes?

Comment: yes indeed. I edited the question to be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using an `RKObjectManager` and routing.

While configuring your mappings, include and item which extracts the `albumId` from the route URL and stores it into a temporary attribute on the song:

```
@"@metadata.routing.parameters.albumId": @"connectionAlbumId",
```

Then, you can add a relationship mapping to connect the song to the appropriate album:

```
[songMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"album" connectedBy:@{ @"connectionAlbumId": @"identity" }];
```

Where `@"identity"` is the name of the attribute holding the identity on the album managed object.

Comment: and shouldn't I add something to the albumMapping as well ?

Comment: and that temporary attribute, shouldn't I make it persistent? as I need it for filtering the songs entities in the fetch request block...

Comment: You can make it persistent if you want to use it for other things. The relationship should be bi-directional so only completing it at one end will also auto-complete the other end (Core Data does that itself).

Comment: Thank you for that, helped me a lot after hours of searching the docs!